Method/Pattern to Maintain Constant Set of Topic Strings in Elixir

I am trying to use the Phoenix Framework's PubSub module in a number of GenServers, however I would like to have a well-defined list of topics to reference instead of raw strings.
Currently my code looks something like this:

# ...

def init(_args) do
  Phoenix.PubSub.subscribe(:my_pubsub, "topic_name")
end

# ...

def handle_info({"topic_name", data = %SomeData{}}, state) do
  # do stuff with data ...
end


# in a  different module:
Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast(:my_pubsub, "topic_name", {"topic_name", %SomeData{key: value}})

This works, but the use of a raw string for the topic name is deficient for several reasons: it requires me to check everywhere that "topic_name" is used to verify that it is spelled correctly, if there is an existing topic name, I need to look through the code to find it, if I misspell it I get no warning, and if I want to examine a list of all possible topics, I have to look through the code and find all the unique topics given in the subscribe or broadcast calls -- this also means I can't give them sensible documentation.
As far as I'm concerned, using atoms for the topic names would have the same problems, but PubSub only allows topics to be strings.
What I'd like is a way to define all topics in one module and reference them AND pattern match on them, like so:
def handle_info({Topics.some_topic, data = %SomeData{}}, state) do
  # do stuff...
end

In every other language I've ever used, this sort of pattern is straightforward.  However, Elixir does not offer any way of sharing constants between modules (at least not any that I could find).  Is there any way I can achieve what I'm looking for or do I need to get used to having things the way I described at the beginning?

In Elixir the notion of "constants" isn't quite the same as it might be in other languages. Atoms are constant in that they are registered into the VM and are not garbage collected.  As far as accessing a value via a name, that happens via functions (as do most things in Elixir).
For example, you can imagine an arity 0 function used to store "constant" values that can be shared across modules and apps:
defmodule Constants
  def pi, do: 3.14
  def some_topic, do: "something"
end

so that Constants.some_topic() or Constants.some_topic (if we drop the optional parens) both yield "something".
However, you can't pattern-match directly on a function output -- this is because the function clauses get compiled and the function's return value isn't normally known until runtime (with some exceptions for macros and the like).  You can bind the value to a variable and pin it, e.g.
def foo(x) do
  pi = Constants.pi()

  case x do
    ^pi -> "PI!"
    _other -> "Not PI"
  end
end

One way to get something that might feel more "global constant"-like would be to use a module attribute, e.g.
defmodule MyMod do
  @topic1 "something"

  def foo(@topic1), do: "We got something"
  def foo(_), do: "nothing"
end

You can pattern match using a module attribute, e.g. MyMood.foo("something") would yield "We got something", but you will notice that module attributes are not available outside the module (this is because they are evaluated at compile-time).  This might frustrate your attempts to organize all topics into a single location, however (but that may not be a bad thing -- it might just be different than what you're used to).
You may decide that it's easier to define a module attribute in the module(s) where it's required.  You can lean on application configuration to be a source of truth for values like this, and you can use the config to hydrate the module attributes, even in different modules, e.g.
defmodule MyMod do
  @topic1 Application.compile_env!(:my_app, :topic1)
  @topic2 Application.compile_env!(:my_app, :topic2)
  # ...
end

If these solutions really a preventing you from writing clean code, you can dip into Elixir's macro layer to build the code you need.  E.g. consider this:
defmodule Topics do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      @topic1 "t1"
      @topic2 "t2"
      # ... etc...
    end
  end
end

This would make the module attributes available inside any module that used the Topics module, e.g.
defmodule MyMod do
  use Topics

  def foo(@topic1), do: "A"
  def foo(@topic2), do: "B"
  # ...
end

so that MyMod.foo("t1") would yield "A".

I understand that sharing constants between modules is not supported, but I can't understand what the rationale might be.  After all, modules share data about functions with each other, so why can't they share constants in a similar way that would allow them to be pattern-matched?  It seems like a missing feature.

Oh, by the way, I did end up getting a third-party package that uses macros to define constants.  I'm still baffled why the language itself doesn't support this though.

This is unfortunately a known limitation of the Erlang VM, which doesn't have a real mechanism for constants.
If you are within the same module, the easiest way is to just use module attribute:
@topic "my_topic"

def subscribe, do: Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast(:my_pubsub, @topic, ...)
def match_topic({@topic, ...}), do: ...

But this would require you to reorganize your code that needs to be aware of the const to fit within one module, which might be a good solution in some cases but doesn't always work.
Solutions across modules could be:
a. define a function, call it as a module attribute
defmodule A do
  def topic, do: "my_topic"
end

defmodule B do
  @topic A.topic()

  def match_topic({@topic, ...}). do: ...
end

b. define a macro (probably overkill)
defmodule A do
  defmacro topic do
    # in this particular case, `quote` is overkill, "my_topic" being its own AST
    quote do: "my_topic"
  end
end

defmodule B do
  require A  # necessary to use it

  def match_topic({A.topic(), ...}). do: ...
end

Since the macro is called at compile-time, it is fine to use it in the pattern (unlike functions).
c. There are some libraries for this, like defconstant which might be useful if you find yourself using this pattern.

How do you get the color formatting of your code examples?

Triple quote + lang-elixir, https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting.
Adding  on the top is more convenient but I always forget the syntax :D
